# Fading color in a loop with C#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, colors, thread-sleep

I'm trying to make the color of a textbox change to green, and then fade back to white as a method of confirmation. Here's the code I have so far:

```
private void btnCommit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff

    Color c = new Color();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        c = Color.FromArgb(i, 255, i);
        textBox1.BackColor = c;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }     
}
```

It doesn't work. It appears to just wait for the 2.5ish seconds before I can do anything else, but the color stays white the whole time.

Comment: btnClick is executing on UI thread and hence you see a freeze. You could use WPF animation instead or async as shown in anwer below or run this code in a background task which updates the BackColor using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: In which context is this used? Have you considered using CSS or LESS for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` blocks your UI Thread (If executed using the UI Thread like your case), you have to use `Task.Delay()` and make your method `async` to make the UI responsive and see the fading animation:

```
private async void btnCommit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff

    Color c = new Color();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        c = Color.FromArgb(i, 255, i);
        textBox1.BackColor = c;

        await Task.Delay(10);
    }     
}
```

Note that the time taken to capture the current context, execute the delay and then resume the context might take the same time (around `20ms`) for small delays (`1ms` vs `20ms`). So you might need to increase the delay a little bit to notice a difference between different delays.

Comment: 1000 milliseconds of waiting per iteration is going to take 255 seconds, I think OP isn't out for that.

Comment: Didn't notice that the counter was 255, fixed.

Comment: Well, it works but this has the same problem of DoEvents. Code reentry. If you click again on the button while you are executing the loop, the loop starts again (and this will be a minor problem if there was no -- do stuff -- comment)

Comment: @Steve I think disabling the button and enabling it after before the end of the method is one solution.

Comment: Thanks! This works great, but it seems that no matter what the time delay is, it always takes the same amount of time -- about 4-5 seconds. I have to change i's interval in order to get the animation to go faster.

Comment: @Fic Well i don't have the `//do stuff` part of my machine, so changing the delay to `100ms` makes the fading takes 25 seconds approx.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It seems like there's threshold to how fast it can go. The animation takes the same amount of time when the interval is at 10 as it does when it's at 1.

Comment: @fic `Task.Delay` is not 100% accurate. For me, the difference between `10ms` and `1ms` taking into consideration the time needed to execute the waiting and resuming the context makes it really non-sense to wait for `1ms`

Comment: @user3185569 Okay. Thanks again!